# WndProc override odd message, cant be proper

Tags: c#, windows

I am looking at the code posted [here](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=10675), specifically  SyntaxRichTextBox.cs at the overriden method `WndProc`.

Is this just a typo in the code? What windows msg is `0x00f`? Did they mean `0x0f` for `WM_PAINT`? And what is the author of the code catching that message?

Code:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == 0x00f)
    {
        if (m_bPaint)
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        else
            m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
    }
    else
        base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Comment: `0x00f` and `0x0f` are the same number.

Comment: So it is for the WM_Paint message, and why would you want to catch that message in this code? (code in the OP URL)

Comment: As if anyone needed more proof, this is a shining example of why it's a bad idea to use magic numbers in your code. If there had been a `public const int WM_PAINT = 0x00f;`, you would not have been confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, as James McNellis suggested in the comment above, 0x00f and 0x0f indicate the same number. I didn't check the value of `WM_PAINT` message, but the code looks like it is handling this message.

It looks like a simple optimization: if `m_bPaint` is `false`, skip the `base.WndProc()` call. Probably `m_bPaint` is a flag that indicates there is something that needs to be redrawn.

Comment: Correct, specifically, this code could be commented "Ignore `WM_Paint` messages when `m_bPaint` is set to `false`".

Comment: I understand that. But in the code in the URL in the OP, why would the author want to suspend painting. He sets m_bPaint specifically in ProcessLines which chooses certain parts of lines and highlights them. Why do you not want to paint during this highlighting?

Comment: Best thing to do would be to disable the code block, and see what happens. But a quick glance at the code suggests that the programmer is setting up selections and changing selection colors to do the syntax highlighting, and doesn't want those partial results to be displayed.

Comment: Indeed, it does indeed appear that the person who wrote the original code is someone who does not know about or understand how to use clipping regions.